# how to printf adress of semaphore in C?

Tags: c, posix, semaphore

I have to print address of semaphore. I create a semaphore:

```
sem_t *sem =  sem_open("name", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, SEM_PERMS, INITIAL_VALUE);
```

I know that sem_open() returns the address of the new semaphore. So I have to print address of this sem. How can I do this? I've tried something like this:

```
printf("address sem: %d\n",sem);
```

id does not work cause its sem_t pointer, have I cast it to char*?

Comment: For pointers use `printf("%p", some_pointer_here);` Also take a look here for additional `printf` format specifiers https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Comment: yea, i ahve to case it to (void*) and than it works, thanks

Comment: Not really, `printf` format specifier `"%p"` works for any type of pointer, since all pointers in the same architecture are the same size.

Comment: `printf("address sem: %p\n", (void*)sem)` is the only correct way.